# Is accuracy a smooth function in binary classification problems?

Tags: gradient-descent, smooth-functions, error-function

As far as I understand, for a binary classifier which outputs are either 0 or 1, the accuracy is same as `1 - MSE` where MSE stands for Mean Square Error. MSE is a smooth function, therefore it is differentiable everywhere. Thus, can we conclude that accuracy (`1 - MSE`) is also a smooth function? I have read many times that accuracy is not a differentiable function and because of that it cannot be used as loss function in gradient-based optimization algorithms. Can some one please clarify it for me?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Smooth functions have continuous derivatives. Doesn't a binary classifier jump at a threshold value?

Comment: Yes it does. Isn't MSE a smooth function for a binary classification problem?